# Can multiple projects have the same context-root?

Tags: java, weblogic, jax-rs

I am going to build a many web services using weblogic and JAX-RS. To keep things simple I was going to place each service in its own project. But the problem I seem to be having is with setting the context-root for each project.

Can multiple projects that are deployed on the save weblogic server have the same context-root?

Answer (score 5):

of course not. how do you expect weblogic knows which web application you are calling?

edit:
however, it is possible to give one web application a context root of `/webapp` and the other `/webapp/ws`

Comment: I would hope it would use either the hostname or the port number.